# Excel table - transpose using vba

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

I'm quite new to the world of VBA, so pardon what might be a very simple question.

If you have a look at the images I will try to explain what my struggle still is. Using "transpose" I manage to get column A to become Row 1. I need column A to stay as column A (notice that they are merged cells), and I need Row 1 to stay as Row 1. Basically I need Column B to turn into Row 2, and the % numbers to transpose.

Now it looks like this:
[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEwn1.jpg)

I want it to look like this:
[wanted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMVny.jpg)

The original table is much larger than the example...

Comment: Can you not copy, paste special, transpose, or does this need to be automated?

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far?

Comment: Prefer it to be automated, as the table is several hundred rows long with numerous columns, as well as I have several different files to modify... 

I have tried to record a macro to see what it looks like, but I am not sure how I can make it run through the whole table without actually doing the whole job. I am reading the "Excel macro for dummies", but I don't have the experience yet to understand how to define my ranges properly or making it loop.

Comment: For this example it looks like `Sheets(1).Range("B3:E" & lastRow).copy : Sheets(2).Range("B2").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True`, and [lastRow formula here](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You should not try to do what you're asking.  What you SHOULD do is change the pivot in SPSS.  Change your A1/A2/A3 data point from a Row to a Column.

You should never automate inefficiency, it's confusing for all those who come after you and have to support it.

Comment: Thanks for the input @n8, unfortunately this is not an option. Let me explain how the structure is set up. Q1 is Question 1 in a survey, A1/2/3 are answer alternatives per questions (repeated), Dep1/2/3 are departments answering the questions (Q) using the alternatives (As). I cannot separate the Qs and the As in colums and rows in SPSS.

Comment: Sounds like you should output the raw data and pivot in Excel instead.  This type of thing should be possible without a bunch of fragile VBA hacking.

Comment: unfortunately not an option as mentioned, but thanks for the input. This cannot be solved using the raw data for excel pivot or spss custom tables as the data is structured differently. I'll keep on researching, hopefully I find a solution. Apparantly this is not out of the box as I cannot "just" transpose the data. Thanks again!

Comment: The problem may be data structure then.  If it is stored in these columns then you can pivot any way you like: Dept, Question Number, Answer Number, Answer Response.  It may be that your source data isn't well structured, which is preventing you from having your needed flexibility.  In any case, good luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

A very basic way would be to copy-paste as-transpose, here's basic code:

```
Sub TransposeColToRow()
' TransposeColToRow Macro
Range("B3:B14").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B20").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

You could probably test something like this to see if it scratches the itch. This could be improved by avoiding Select like below (this assumes the Copy range is on a sheet called Sheet 1 and the Paste range is on a sheet called Sheet2 - these would need to reflect reality of your spreadsheet of course):

```
Dim CopyRange as Range: Set CopyRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3:B14")
Dim PasteRange as Range: Set PasteRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:M2")

CopyRange.Copy
PasteRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
```

Comment: Thanks @jcd, this helps a lot as it almost "scratches the itch". If you have a look at my original images I will try to explain what my struggle still is. With the basic code I manage to get column A to become Row 1. I need column A to stay as column A (notice that they are merged cells), and I need Row 1 to stay as Row 1. Basically I need Column B to turn into Row 2, and the % from C2:E13 to change direction. Sorry for the clumsy explanation!